# convergence of a numerical series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to study the convergence of the numerical serie
$$
S_n=\sum_{k= 1}^n u_k=\sum_{k= 1}^n \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[k]{2}+\log k\right)^{k^2}}.
$$
I tried the Cauchy rule (i.e. evaluate $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}(u_k)^{\frac 1 k}$ but there is no issue.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series
$$S=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[k]{2}+\log k\right)^{k^2}}$$
is convergent by comparison with a geometric series, since:
$$ \left(\sqrt[k]{2}+\log k\right)^{k^2} \geq 2^k,$$
hence $S\leq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac1{\left(\sqrt[k]2+\log k)\right)^{k^2}}<\frac1{\sqrt[k]{2}^{k^2}}$$